# LLVM Instrumenting C++ lock and unlock functions

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

**Intent**: Given some source code, my intent is to instrument entry/exit of critical sections and associated lock/s.

**Approach**: I used a function pass which basically iterate over all direct function calls, and check name against my `{mutex}.lock()` and `{mutex}.unlock()` mangled names.

**Issue**: I don't know how to get mutex instance on which lock() is called and then pass it to my hook function(ex. enter_cs(mtx)) as argument.

I looked at .ll code and saw this

```
call void @_ZNSt3__15mutex4lockEv(%"class.std::__1::mutex"* nonnull dereferenceable(64) @mtx)
```

I don't know how can I get access to @mtx.
I am new to LLVM so please help. Also if there is better approach for overall problem, please explain!

sample code:

```
mutex mtx;

void enter_cs(mutex mtx) {
    /** some code **/
    return;
}

void exit_cs(mutex mtx) {
    /** some code **/
    return;
}

int main() {
    mtx.lock();
    /** LLVM inserted call: enter_cs(mtx) **/
    // critical section code //
    mtx.unlock();
    /** LLVM inserted call: exit_cs(mtx) **/
    return 0;
}
```

LLVM Pass:

```
static StringRef mutexLock = "_ZNSt3__15mutex4lockEv";
bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
    for(BasicBlock &bb : F) {
            for(Instruction &i : bb) {
                    if(!isa<CallInst>(i)) continue; // should be a call instruction
                    CallInst *ci = cast<CallInst>(&i);
                    Function* f = ci->getCalledFunction();
                    if(!f) continue; // should be a direct call
                    if(f->getName()==mutexLock) {
                        errs() << "locked" << ", From: " << F.getName() << "\n";
                        /** enter_cs({mutex object on which lock is called}) **/
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: [f->getArgOperand(0)](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallBase.html#ab2caa29167597390ab2fc3cf30d70389) should return the mutex, ie. an instruction whose runtime value will be the mutex.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw It should be `ci->getArgOperand(0)->getName()`. Is there any way I could get the `mutex` instance itself to pass to any hook function rather than name? getArgOperand returns `Value`.

Comment: The `Value*` you get from `getArgOperand()` is that... sort of. Precisely what it is depends on the code generator that made the IR. If the mutex is a gloabal variable it may be that very `GlobalVariable*`, if it's a member variable (in e.g. C++) it may be a `LoadInst*` whose first argument is a `GetElementPtrInst*`, or or may be other things. Analysing code before it runs is tricky. There are a few cases, not many, in which [LLVM's support for constant folding](https://llvm.org/doxygen/ConstantFolding_8h.html) may help you.